# Are there reserved names for JQuery Selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I had an accidentally misspelled selector like this:

```js
$("#cut")
```

And it was NOT retrieving the object appropriately; I definitely had an object with that id defined on the HTML that existed. I tried changing the object's id *(and the selector's call)* and it worked like a charm, so I'm 99% I somehow can't use `$("#cut")` as selector.

Are there any other cases that might be interesting to learn?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: I misspelled the selector as `$("#cut#")` here once, that's an error here, it was not like that on the code. Sorry for that!

Comment: `"#cut#"` or `"#cut"`??? I'm just guessing your observation is wrong. Maybe you have more than one element with `cut` as ID

Comment: `$("#cute\\#")` will let you use this id.

Comment: You probably have two DOM elements with that ID in the document

Answer (score 1):

Q: `"Are there reserved names for JQuery Selectors?"`

A: **No.**

Wish there was a more in-depth answer for you, but that's pretty much the gist of it.

For more information on valid jQuery selectors, check out their docs [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Answer (score -1):

Yes you are correct. `#cut#` is not a valid selector - hence why jQuery can not find it. But stripping the last `#` will make it a valid selector.

The question is really what type of values the `id` attribute on an HTML element will allow. The hash-sign is definitely one of the reserved characters.

Comment: This is not relevant since the OP updated their answer